# Unramified constituent of Weil representation of $U(2)$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, automorphic-forms, p-adic-groups

Let $E/F$ be a quadratic extension of local field of characteristic zero.

Let $\omega$ be the quadratic character of $F^{\times}$ associated to $E/F$ by local class field theory and $\gamma:E^{\times} \to \mathbb{C}$ be a unitary character whose restriction to $F^{\times}$ is $\omega$.

Let $W_2$ be a $n$-dimensional hermitian space over $E$ and $U(W_2)$ its isometry unitary group.

Let $\Omega_{2,\gamma}$ be the Weil representation of $U(W_2)$ associated to $\gamma$.

Then is it true that the unramified piece of $\Omega_{2,\gamma}$ is the unramified constituent of the representation induced from the character $\gamma$ of the Borel group of $U(W_2)$?

I don't know why it does true. Is there any reference regarding this?

Thank you in advance.